# Automatically show the Choose file option/button when a checkbox is selected

Tags: visualforce, javascript, inputcheckboxes, apexinputfile

Suppose I have one checkbox and one inputfile (Choose File). The idea is whenever I select/check the checkbox (checkbox value=true) then the ChooseFile (inputfile) will be automatically displayed in my visualforce page. Please Help me for this scenario, I've got the following page code & controller code but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
<apex:inputCheckbox value="{!option}" >
    <apex:actionsupport event="onclick" action="{!change}" reRender="pg"/>
</apex:inputCheckbox>                

<apex:inputFile value="AttachFile"  rendered="{!bool}"/>



public Boolean option {get;set;}
public Boolean bool {get;set;}
public extHospitals(){
    bool = false;
}
public void change() {
    if(option == true){  
        bool = true; 
    }
    else { 
        bool = false;  
    }
}
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking! Give more information about the problem.

Comment: suppose i have one checkbox and one inputfile (Choose File). when ever i want to selects/check (checkbox value=true) then automatically the ChooseFile (inputfile) will be populate in my visualforce page. Please Help me for this scenario

Comment: And what is the problem you are facing? Is something wrong with your code, or maybe you are getting some error message? Have you tried something so far?

Comment: Visualforce Page  <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!option}" >
                    <apex:actionsupport event="onclick" action="{!change}" reRender="pg"/>
                </apex:inputCheckbox>                
   <apex:inputFile value="AttachFile"  rendered="{!bool}"/>       Contoller : public Boolean option {get;set;}
    public Boolean bool {get;set;}
    public extHospitals(){
         bool = false;
    }
    public void change() {
        if(option == true)   {  bool = true; }
        else { bool = false;  }
    }

Comment: You better edit your questions text instead of posting the code in a comment.

Comment: now is it better?

Comment: Much better :-)

Comment: so give me suggestion for this one

Answer (score 0):

Try using following code :

```
 <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!option}" >
     <apex:actionsupport event="onclick" action="{!change}" />
 </apex:inputCheckbox>                
 <apex:actionRegion rendered="{!bool}">
     <apex:inputFile value="AttachFile" />
 </apex:actionRegion>
```